# Not able to get output with glDrawElements() & glMultiDrawElements()

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, vertex-array, vertex-attributes, vertexdata

I'm in the process of building a graphics app where the user can specify vertices by clicking on a canvas and then the vertices are used to draw polygons.

The app supports line, triangle and polygon modes. Drawing a line and triangle is done by counting the number of clicks. Then vertex arrays are created and data is bound to buffers and rendered using `glDrawArrays()`. The tricky one is the polygon mode. The user can specify any number of vertices and clicking right mouse button triggers drawing. I initially planned to use `glMultiDrawElements`, but somehow I wasn't getting any output. So I tried to call `glDrawElements()` in a loop. still with no luck. I searched a lot and read a lot of documentation about using `glDrawElements()/glMultiDrawElements()` with VBOs and VAOs and also with `glVertexPointer()` and `glColorPointer`. Still no luck.

I have used the following for keeping track of vertex attributes:

GLfloat ** polygonVertices; //every polygon vertex list goes into this..
    
GLuint * polygonIndicesCounts;  //pointer to hold the number of vertices each polygon has
    
GLuint ** polygonIndices;    //array of pointers to hold indices of vertices corresponding to polygons
    
GLfloat * polygonColors; //for every mouse click, colors are randomly generated.

and the code for rendering:

```
glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, (GLvoid*)polygonVertices);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, (GLvoid*)polygonColors);

//glMultiDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, polygonIndicesCounts, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, polygonIndices, polygonCount);

for(int i = 0 ; i < polygonCount; i ++)
    glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, polygonIndicesCounts[i], GL_UNSIGNED_INT, polygonIndices[i]);
```

Comment: Any GL errors? Are you positive your data is correct?

Comment: Hi thokra, there were no errors. I tried to go glGetError() also. But nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are *polygonVertices* pointers to pointers? If you cast that to `(void*)` the only thing OpenGL sees is the value of pointer to which each points. You want those to be flat a array, so their type signature should be compatible with `float*` (not `float**`). A pointer to a pointer makes sense only for the *glMultiDrawArrays* call.

Comment: Hi datenwolf, the ** version works. I didn't have to flatten it. The following worked:

`GLfloat vertices[4][3] = {
{0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f},
{-0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f},
{0.2f, -0.2f, 0.0f},
{-0.2f, -0.2f, 0.0f}
};

GLfloat colors[12] = {
0.32f, 0.92f, 0.30f,
0.32f, 0.12f, 0.50f,
0.82f, 0.42f, 0.80f,
0.52f, 0.72f, 0.10f
};

GLuint indices []= {0, 1, 3, 2};

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);
glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);`

Comment: @AnkurHuralikoppi: This particular version works, because you're allocating an multidimensional array in automatic memory. The C language standard specifies, that in this particular situation all the elements in the multidimensional array *must* be contiguous. However the `**` is still wrong. Because what happens if you do this: `GLfloat **a2 = malloc(sizeof(float*)*4); for(int i=0; i<4; i++) a2[i] = malloc(sizeof(float)*3);`. In that case if you passed `*a2` to OpenGL, all OpenGL sees in only the very first (i=0) block of 3 floats allocated, but the rest will be somewhere else.

Comment: @AnkurHuralikoppi: To make a long story short: **NEVER** use pointers to pointers to pointers to … for multidimensional data. **ALWAYS** allocate a flat buffer of `malloc(width * height * depth * …);` (or equivalent `new`) and address with `[… + width*height*z + width*y + x]`. Everything else is madness. Also very inefficient, because each and every pointer level introduces a costly indirection that's hard on the cache.

Comment: I flattened the arrays and then copied the indices in GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER and then used index offsets. That solved the problem!